# Compatibility IBM DS3400 with 3TB sata disk

Tags: storage-area-network, ibm

I've a IBM DS3400 with 4 disks sata 500GB and 5 disks 146GB SAS

I want enlarge my sata storage with 3TB disks.. what i've to do?

first question: Does IBM DS3400 recognize 3TB sata disks ?
second question: Do you think that i've to create a temporary array on 2 free slots to copy and preserve my data and then i must destroy the 500x4 array before create a new 3000x4 pool ? Or can i enlarge the array replacing the 500gb disk with the 3000gb ones like with ZFS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the compatability matrix the DS3400 doesn't support 3TB drives. IBM haven't shipped 3TB drives in more or less anything until quite recently. There doesn't seem to be any note in the firmware changelog to increase support.

With regard to the expansion, you will have to destroy/recreate - you can't expand that way unfortunately

Compatability Matrix:
http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/resources/systems_storage_disk_ds3000_pdf_interop.pdf

Firmware Changelog:
http://delivery04.dhe.ibm.com/sar/CMA/SDA/03r9h/2/ibm_fw_ds3k_07357300_anyos_anycpu.chg